# d3.dispatch() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have started working with D3.js a week ago and am currently trying to figure out how d3.dispatch() works. I have a super simplistic example

```
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var dispatch = d3.dispatch("load","click");

dispatch.load("Initial Value");

dispatch.on("load", function(textvalue) {
  alert(textvalue);


  dispatch.on("click", function(newvalue) {
    alert(newvalue);
  });
});

</script>
```

I would have expected that the listener `dispatch.on("load",function(textvalue){}` would have reacted to the previous line `dispatch.load("Initial Value");` by displaying a JavaScript alert, yet it does not. After Lars' response (thanks Lars, it made sense... just one more question...) I edited the code to read thus:

```
 d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, states) {  
  dispatch.load("Initial Value");  
});

dispatch.on("load", function(textvalue) {
  alert(textvalue);         

  dispatch.on("click", function(state) {
    select.text(state);
  });
});
</script>
```

I just changed the call `dispatch.load` to be within a `d3.csv()` call, and this seems to me to still be calling `load()` before the handler is defined, yet in this case it does work. What gives? P.S also new to JavaScript so forgive the naivety.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is simply in the wrong order -- by the time you call `.load()`, the handler for this event hasn't been defined. It works when you rearrange the code so that the handler is defined before you call it.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9kmg7fk/).

Comment: I edited the code (see above edit) and am still confused why in the new code, even though am calling load before defining the handler it seems to work?

Comment: `d3.csv` is asynchronous -- the code in the callback handler isn't executed immediately, but when the network request returns (which is after the handlers have been defined).